# Unit testing method which only calls a single dependency method - c#/xUnit/Moq

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

Ashamed to admit it, but unit testing is still new to me. I have a pretty firm grasp on how to handle things properly. But a situation I find hard to understand the point of is when writing a unit test for a method that simply returns the result of a dependency method invocation.

I find it's come up a few times in situations where you're implementing a service layer to interop with your DAL layer.

A trivial code example will probably better describe what I'm asking.

> Note: The code example below is using **c#, xUnit and Moq**.

```
public class Foo {
    Bar int;
    Baz string;
}

public interface IFooRepository {
    Foo GetByBar(bar int);
}

public interface IFooService {
    Foo GetByBar(bar int);
}

public class FooService : IFooService {
    private IFooRepository fooRepository;

    public FooService(
        IFooRepository fooRepository){
        this.fooRepository = fooRepository; 
    }

    public Foo GetByBar(bar int)
    {
        return fooRepository.GetByBar(bar);
    }
}

[Fact]
public class FooServiceTests 
{
    public class GetByBarMethod 
    {
        [Fact]
        public void ShouldReturnBar()
        {
            //arrange
            var expectedFoo = new Foo() { Bar = 1, Baz = "baz" };
            var repo = new Mock<IFooRepository>();
            repo.Setup(r => r.GetByBar(1)).Returns(expectedFoo);

            var service = new FooService(repo.Object);

            //act
            var result = service.GetByBar(1);

            //assert
            Assert.Same(result, expectedFoo);
        }
    }   
}
```

I understand that the point of the `FooService` unit tests is to test the logic within the methods, not that of the dependencies. So is there even a point to write a test in this case, if it's simply testing a mocked dependency's return value?

Comment: You are testing that the method under test will behave as expected. While in this case it is rather simplified. Don't focus on implementation concerns. Sure ultimately the test is getting the value from a dependency, the goal is to test that the method under test behaves as expected when exercised.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback! I understand that much, as mentioned toward the end of the question. I just wanted to confirm that my logic was sound (i.e. testing here made sense, despite the simplicity).

Comment: Yes the testing makes sense.

Comment: It's not so much which method you are testing but what you are testing for. In this case, what you really want to test is that the repository is being used by the service. It is passed as a dependency to your service, but what guarantees that the code is actually calling the repo within it? So your test name would become `ShouldUseRepository` or something of the sort. You can then check that the repo's `GetByBar` method is called.

Comment: @JuanR great way to elucidate. Can you explain how you'd assert the method is called? Aside from checking the result which is mocked. Or is that the way?

Comment: @pimbrouwers moq has a verify method you can use to verify that a member has been invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is meant to answer your comment

> Can you explain how you'd assert the method is called?

There are two ways

First would be to make the `Setup` expectation `Verifiable()`

```
repo
    .Setup(r => r.GetByBar(1))
    .Returns(expectedFoo)
    .Verifiable();
```

and then assert it after invocation

```
//...code removed for brevity

//act
var result = service.GetByBar(1);

//assert
repo.Verify(); //Verifies that all verifiable expectations have been met.
```

The second would be using an expression similar to the `Setup` in the `Verify`

For example

```
//...code removed for brevity

//act
var result = service.GetByBar(1);

//assert
Assert.Same(result, expectedFoo);
repo.Verify(r => r.GetByBar(1));
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

Comment: Is Verifiable really necessary? I've used Verify plenty but never use Verifiable.